# How can I connect a mac (or windows) app to iOS as a standard bluetooth keyboard/controller?

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, bluetooth

My mac app has a companion iOS app and needs to send it basic controls such as a shortcut in the mac app (ie: cmd+delete or the arrow keys) performs an action in the iOS app. I fiddled with a server/websockets setup sending/listening to commands but thats excessive and requires internet and server power. I'd like to do it over bluetooth locally.

It seems something just like what Type2iPhone (https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/type2phone/id472717129?mt=12) does would be perfect just supporting the mac app as a standard bluetooth keyboard and then listening to keyboard events in the iOS app and responding or probably even simpler since I just need a few commands would be supporting the gamepad controller/extended controller (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/ServicesDiscovery/Conceptual/GameControllerPG/Introduction/Introduction.html) in the app and sending the appropriate commands from the mac (this should also enable me to easily integrate with other apps in the future too if they just simply respond to controller or keyboard events that I send consistently instead of something custom)

I have no experience with bluetooth so I'm looking to be pointed in the right direction to set this up, ie: pairing bluetooth (with the phone not just my app so other apps may listen too in the future), how to send appropriate commands etc.. I've looked for an Apple doc that shows this but can't find it - do you have to be part of the MFi program to get it or is it something I can just setup if I have the spec? I don't see any MFi logos or anything on type2iphone and it's in the mac store so I assume MFi license is not necessarily required.

Is stack the right place for this since it's a little more general/broad?

Comment: Did you look at the WWDC 2012 sessions? https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=705_

Comment: Thanks @NSPunk a few BT ones in there and a good one in the 2013 videos. Also led me to search corebluetooth and bluetooth peripheral which brought back good results - even a code sample on git https://github.com/liquidx/CoreBluetoothPeripheral

Comment: Good to hear you found useful!

Comment: Spoke too soon. It's useful for proprietary stuff, but not quite what I need to simulate a standard bluetooth HID like a keyboard/controller so that other apps can more easily integrate with it. Should be able to do the keyboard option with standard bluetooth HID tech but it's much more complicated than the CoreBluetooth APIs from Apple... Would likely need an MFi license to do the controller option.